# Is it true that there will always be a .lib(import library) associated with the .dll you build?

Tags: c++, c, dll

Or do I need to instruct the compiler explicitly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a user name like "ieplugin" the answer would probably be No.  COM servers don't have .lib files.  For regular DLLs, the .lib file is produced by the linker, not the compiler.  The /IMPLIB option generates them.

Comment: While you don't normally *use* the .lib file with a COM server, it *is* normally produced. Just for example, if you create a default "ActiveX Control" project with MSVC++, and compile it, the build log will contain a line like: "1>   Creating library c:\c\projects\whatever\Debug\whatever.lib and object c:\c\projects\whatever\Debug\whatever.exp"

Comment: Is it true that we can only use `.dll` either by the import library or load the `.dll` programatically(`c/c++`),no 3rd way?

Comment: ieplugin, as far as I know, yes. What kind of 3rd way would you like to use? I think a lot of cool things can be done by loading DLLs at runtime already and by using them as interchangable/patchable libs.

Comment: Mingw can link directly to the DLL in most cases, it doesn't *require* an explicit import lib (although gcc import libs are *.a files, not .lib, but the idea is the same).

Answer (score 0):

It normally happens automatically (for any DLL *or* executable that exports at least one symbol). Edit: at least with the compilers I've used; I suppose there could be a compiler that didn't produce one automatically -- I'm pretty sure there are at least a few versions of a few compilers that I haven't tried/used.